# Tooltip in bubble chart using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I am using d3.js for bubble chart.its working fine but i need to write custom tool tip for the data which i am showing.currently i just appended one title tag so it just showing one data with tooltip 
what if i have more data to show and want to show in form of a table.

Here is my code.

```
d3.json("data/bubble.json", function(error, root) {
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))

  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });



node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".3em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});
```

Comment: This should answer your query I think: http://bl.ocks.org/jdonaldson/1209105

Comment: how can i make all the circle in increasing order of there radius .. or decreasing order .. like biggest circle would be left side then circles with radius less then first like that